# Cant add collection_select while using materialize rails 4.2

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, materialize

I have created a categories model with a migration with a category_id (basically everything Mackenzie Child does in his video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=814gCeOpM4o from 25minutes) and I want it to show up in my form.

It doesn't work, my `collection_select` wont show up on screen but it will show up in the source code, and when I 'remove' the css- framework materialize.

My code:

```
<div class="container"> 
<div class="row">
    <%= form_for @post do |f| %>
        <%= f.collection_select :category_id, Category.all, :id, :name, { prompt: "Choose a category" } %>
        <br>
        <%= f.label :title %>
        <%= f.text_field :title %>
        <br>
        <br>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s12">
                <%= f.label :text %>
                <%= f.text_area :text, class: "materialize-textarea" %>
            </div>
        </div>

        <br>
        <br>
        <%= f.label :creator %>
        <%= f.text_field :creator %><br>
        <%= f.submit %>
    <% end %>   
</div>
```

How it's displayed in the source code:

```
    <select name="post[category_id]" id="post_category_id"><option value="">Choose a category</option>
        <option value="1">Marketing</option>
        <option value="2">Technology</option>
        <option value="3">Programming</option>
        <option value="4">Health and Fitness</option>
   </select>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I looked in the materialize documentation and i found out that i just had to add the class browser-default to my collection-select (link to docs http://materializecss.com/forms.html)

```
    <%= f.collection_select :category_id, Category.all, :id, :name, { prompt: "Choose a category" }, class: "browser-default" %>
```

Comment: This solution fixes it for me, too.  But then you don't get the Materialize select menu. :(

Answer (score 1):

If you want your select boxes to render the Materialize CSS way instead of the browser default, then remove the `browser-default` class and initialize the select box with this code in the relevant `.coffee` file:

```
$(document).ready ->
  $('select').material_select
  return
```

look under `app/assets/javascripts/` for the file to put it in.

Also if you are also using turbolinks with jQuery you will need to add the [`jquery.turbolinks` gem](https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks) to make the `$document.ready` function work.

Remember to restart your rails server after adding `jquery.turbolinks`

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Toby 1 Kenobi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2871922/toby-1-kenobi)'s answer and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36110789/rails-5-how-to-use-document-ready-with-turbo-links) my solution, using Rails 5, was to change `$(document).ready` to `$(document).on('turbolinks:load')` like so:

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  $('select').material_select();
})
```