# Rails 5: how to use $(document).ready() with turbo-links

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, turbolinks, ruby-on-rails-5

Turbolinks prevents normal `$(document).ready()` events from firing on all page visits besides the initial load, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18770517/rails-4-how-to-use-document-ready-with-turbo-links) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18769109/rails-4-turbo-link-prevents-jquery-scripts-from-working/18770219#18770219). None of the solutions in the linked answers work with Rails 5, though. How can I run code on each page visit like in prior versions?

Answer (score 183, accepted):

Rather than listen to the `ready` event, you need to hook in to an event fired by Turbolinks for every page visit.

Unfortunately, Turbolinks 5 (which is the version that appears in Rails 5) has been re-written, and does not use the same event names as in previous versions of Turbolinks, causing the answers mentioned to fail. What works now is to listen to the [turbolinks:load](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#running-javascript-when-a-page-loads) event like so:

```
$( document ).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  console.log("It works on each visit!")
})
```

Comment: Yes. Explained here  as well. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#turbolinks. Check 5.2 Page Change Events.

Comment: turbolinks:load fires for me locally, but not on Heroku. I see my custom javascript code in my compiled js assets, but the event isn't firing.

Comment: this not work well. I have a select2 and when change the page and back I have two select2 (duplicated)

Comment: Yes that's true @inye I have the same issue and I also have opened a issue at [GitHub](https://github.com/mkhairi/materialize-sass/issues/130). Have you solved somehow?

Comment: Despite what the Rail doc says, I'm using `on('ready turbolinks:load')` otherwise I have some problems on some pages

Comment: Hi Cyril, I am having the same problem, i.e. need to trigger on initial page load as well as turbolinks:load. I have asked a question about this on SO, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41421496/turbolinks-load-event-not-working-on-with-page-refresh. Do you have any more insight as to why this is so?  Are you using  jquery-turbolinks  (I am).  The only good thing is it makes sure your code is idempotent.

Comment: For me, `$(document).on('turbolinks:load', ...)` did _not_ work; I had to use `document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', ...` as described in the [Turbolinks README](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks/blob/master/README.md#running-javascript-when-a-page-loads).

Comment: @bovender That worked but I'm using a jquery upload button and file field with a progress bar. It adds another progress bar every time the page loads.

Comment: and could be used as following:
```$(document).on 'ready, turbolinks:load', ->```
?

Comment: @CyrilDuchon-Doris That only makes it fire twice, hence why it isn't mentioned in the doc. As github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks/#observing-navigation-events says, you should do it like this: `$(document).ready(function() { $(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {} ) })`

Comment: Is this different for rails 6?

Answer (score 68):

Native JS :

```
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function() {
    console.log('It works on each visit!');
});
```

Comment: `turbo:load` for Turbo

Answer (score 14):

In rails 5 the easiest solution is to use:

```
$(document).on('ready turbolinks:load', function() {});
```

Instead of `$(document).ready`. Works like a charm.

Comment: Don't add `ready` to the list, otherwise the function will be executed twice. As https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks/#observing-navigation-events said, you should do it like this: 

```javascript

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {} )
})

```

Comment: @XiaohuiZhang Are you sure that's gonna work???? Because if `$(document).ready` gets triggered, then at least in my own scenarios, I wouldn't need `turbolinks:load`

Comment: @XiaohuiZhang If your script has to work on a page with turbolinks and on a page without, that will not work on the page without, because it will need the turbolinks:load event to execute the code

Comment: @escanxr It works both, you can try it out. because Turbolinks always trigger "turbolinks:load" event whenever a Turbolinks page or not.

Comment: @XiaohuiZhang I tried with Turbolinks 5, it didn't work. If turbolinks is disabled on the page, only `ready` event is triggered. If there's turbolinks, the code is called twice

Answer (score 9):

This is my solution, override `jQuery.fn.ready`, then `$(document).ready` works without any change:

```
jQuery.fn.ready = (fn)->
  $(this).on 'turbolinks:load', fn
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. This works for external libraries that rely on `document` callbacks as well. Why the downvote? This should be safe as long as turbolinks is used throughout the entire application, right?

Answer (score 3):

(For coffeescript)

I Use:
 `$(document).on 'turbolinks:load', ->`

Instead of:
 `$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {...})`

Comment: I have done that and I still getting this issue as @inye said : https://github.com/mkhairi/materialize-sass/issues/130. Using JS or Coffee does not really make any difference, at least NOT for me.

Comment: Hi folks, what is wrong with this answer in general?

Comment: My guess is that this is coffeescript and not native javascript? I gave it a +1 because this is exactly what I'm doing and it works for me (in my coffeescript file)

Comment: yes!, it is for coffeescript :). My mistake was not to specify it

Answer (score 3):

pure modern js:

```
const onLoad = () => {
  alert("works")
}

document.addEventListener("load", onLoad)
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", onLoad)
```

with turbo it's `turbo:load`

Answer (score 2):

Here is solution that work for me, from [here](https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks/issues/61#issuecomment-246404796):

1. install `gem 'jquery-turbolinks'`
2. add this .coffee file to your app: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks/blob/master/src/turbolinks/compatibility.coffee
3. name it turbolinks-compatibility.coffee
4. at application.js

   ```
   //= require jquery
   //= require jquery_ujs
   //= require jquery.turbolinks
   //= require turbolinks
   //= require turbolinks-compatibility
   ```

Comment: What about in `production` env? Have you tested it out? There are some people telling it just work fine in `development` mode.

Comment: The gem is deprecated

Answer (score 1):

While we await the fix to this really cool gem, I was able to move forward by modifying the following;

```
  addCallback: (callback) ->
if $.turbo.isReady
  callback($)
$document.on 'turbo:ready', -> callback($)
```

to:

```
  addCallback: (callback) ->
if $.turbo.isReady
  callback($)
$document.on 'turbolinks:load', -> callback($)
```

I'm not yet aware what this does not resolve, but it seemed to work well on initial inspection.

Answer (score 0):

Use the light-weight gem [jquery-turbolinks](https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks).

It makes `$(document).ready()` work with Turbolinks without changing existing code.

Alternatively, you could change `$(document).ready()` to one of:

```
$(document).on('page:fetch', function() { /* your code here */ });

$(document).on('page:change', function() { /* your code here */ });
```

depending on which one is more appropriate in your situation.

Comment: jquery-turbolinks doesn't yet support Turbolinks 5 https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks/issues/56

Comment: You're right, @AndrewH! Hopefully, the support will be added soon.

Comment: The jquery-turbolinks gem has been deprecated.