# Turbolinks load event not working on with page refresh

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

Javascript code like this

```
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function() {
  $("p#hide_if_js").hide();
});
```

is working fine with turbolinks when I click between pages or use the browser back button. However, when I refresh the page, the javascript code is not loaded. If I refresh a few times, nothing happens, but if I click a link to a different back and click back to the page, the javascript code is now loaded.

It looks like the turbolinks:load is working on most events, but not the page reload.   The documentation says that it 'fires once on the initial page load and again after every Turbolinks visit'.  What is going wrong?

I am using the jquery.turbolinks gem and the associated [compatibility](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks/blob/master/src/turbolinks/compatibility.coffee) code.

Comment: i think the jquery.turbolinks gem might be out of date if you are using Turbolinks version 5.0

Comment: you can implement this in separate function `function() {
  $("p#hide_if_js").hide();
});`  and added where you need to use this `document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load",func) document.addEventListener("ready",func)`

Comment: In regard to Timmy Von Heiss's comment. According to this video, https://gorails.com/episodes/upgrade-to-turbolinks-5, it can be made to work. Also in my case, all the jquery is working on every time of load page change except a page load.   This is highly unusual for me, normally with turbolinks, most things are flakey, except for a page load.

Comment: I tried uzaif's comment, and it definitely fixes the page load, but now the other events are flaky, i.e. mostly it works but sometimes it does not render the page properly.

Comment: uzaif's approach does seem to improve things, I will do more testing and get back on this.

Comment: Why don't you just wrap in $(document).on("turbolinks:load", function() { }); ?? Does it work if it's not in coffee script?

Comment: I have tried it with straight javascript and it does not work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With help from [uzaif's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3786332/uzaif) comment, the following worked

```
  ready = ->
    if $('body').attr('data-loaded') == 'T'
      return
    # code goes here
    $('body').attr('data-loaded','T')
  $(document).ready(ready)
  $(document).on('turbolinks:load', ready)
```

The `$('body').attr('data-loaded')` lines are to prevent the code loading twice.

This approach is using event delegation, as recommended by the turbolinks instructions.  It is not clear why it is still necessary to use the `$(document).ready(ready)` as the `turbolink:load` is meant to cover this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use in this manner

```
document.addEventListener('load turbolinks:load',function() {
//Your code
});
```

equivalent coffee code

```
document.addEventListener 'load turbolinks:load', ->
  #Your code
  return
```

Comment: I tried this, but it did not help.  Perhaps you could explain why you think it can help. I am also interested in the coffeescript equivalent of this code.

Comment: In above code the listener has been added for 2 kinds of event.
The first one i.e load will execute the js code when your are refreshing the page(The problem which you were facing)
The second one is when the page is loaded via turbolinks
.

Comment: Are u getting any js error in browser console?Please share if there is any.

Comment: I tried this again and it does not work for me.  There ere no errors in browser console or the server log, the event is simply not firing.

Comment: @Obromios Yeah I am seeing the same issue.

Comment: That doesn't work. document.addEventListener doesn't have support for multiple events. Check the docs here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

For me, the correct was to do `$(document).on('ready turbolinks:load', function { …`

Comment: I had to put a comma between the two ie `$(document).on('ready, turbolinks:load', function { …` otherwise the functions attach twice on page load.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  // enter code here
});
```