# Javascript not working on page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

So I have this block of code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  planSelectionForm.init($("form#new_account"));
});
```

And when I link to this page it works as expected. But when I refresh from the browser it doesn't get triggered. This seems like a common problem. Just for the record I'm using turbolinks. Any help on why this is happening would be great!

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't get triggered? Add a `console.log('triggered');` just inside your document ready.  I'm guessing that appears every time, BUT it may depend on where this script is located, where you are loading jQuery, etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Turbolinks load event not working on with page refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41421496/turbolinks-load-event-not-working-on-with-page-refresh)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only solution I could find after getting this problem was wrapping my script with:

```
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function() {
  planSelectionForm.init($("form#new_account"));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your .onready() functions into a function called initialize. The point, is to seperate the event-driven function calls such that the event driven function call calls a global function.

In there, add to your body or another element that supports onload.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  initialize();
});
function initialize()
{
}

<body onload="initialize(); return;"> </body>
```

Also, for Caleb, in my experiance, I believe jQuery ready events only get executed on either a fresh load, or a ctrl+f5 cache reload.