# JavaScript stops working when I refresh page

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have this block of JavaScript code:

```
var input = document.getElementById("password_field");
input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
   event.preventDefault();
   document.getElementById("login").click();
  }
});

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    if (user) {
        document.getElementById("user_div").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("login_div").style.display = "none";

        var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

        if(user != null) {
            var email_id = user.email;
            var email_verified = user.emailVerified;
            document.getElementById('user_para').innerHTML = "You are logged in as<strong> " + email_id + "</strong>.";
            if (email_verified === false) {
                document.getElementById('user_verified').innerHTML = "<strong>You are not verified. Please check for an email from perason for a verification link. You will not be able to access anything without verification.";
            } else {
                document.getElementById('user_verified').innerHTML = "";
                document.getElementById('sandboxaccess').style.display = "block";
            }
        }
      
      
    } else {
        document.getElementById("user_div").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("login_div").style.display = "block";
    }
  });

function login () {
    var userEmail = document.getElementById('email_field').value;
    var userPass = document.getElementById('password_field').value;

    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(userEmail, userPass).catch(function(error) {
        // Handle Errors here.
        var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message;
        window.alert("Error: " + errorMessage);
      });


    
}

function logout() {
    firebase.auth().signOut();
}
```

It works fine initially, but when I refresh the page, all of the JavaScript stops working. It works perfectly fine on Apache localhost (refreshing works on localhost too). What is the solution to this?

Here it is before refresh:

[before refresh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Gnp4.png)

Here it is after refresh:

[after refresh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AOhVO.png)

The logout button is in both.

[Errors on console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0b7m.png)

Comment: what errors do you see in the browser developer tools console?

Comment: it might depends on firebase data stored in localstorage or session storage data. so can you plz try to post the error you might get on console?

Comment: It seems the only likely problem is upon refresh, the `user` is `null`. You should `console.log()`  the user and see what you get on page re-load. My guess is `null`

Comment: since none of the code you've shown includes the word `textContent` the error is somewhere else

Comment: Please edit the question to show the complete code the reproduces the issue.  I also suggest adding more logging, and share the results of that, so we can see how the code executes when the page is loaded.

Comment: textContext is not defined. find out why that is not defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this line of code from your program:

```
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser
```

You already have a `user` object as the parameter of your callback function.  The currentUser returned here might actually be wrongly null and overwriting the correct one being passed in.

Comment: If it was helpful to you, on Stack Overflow, it's customary to upvote and accept as correct this answer using the buttons to the left.

Comment: Yes, I did, but my reputation is under 15 as I'm a new user so my vote will not display to you.

Comment: You can still accept the answer as correct using the checkmark, right?

Answer (score 0):

I think the code is executed before the DOM is loaded.
how about this:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function (){
  // your code
});
```

Comment: That doesn't explain why it works in the first place.

Comment: @RandyCasburn - script loading can be tricky ... who knows if OP has defered or async tags on scripts, browser cache can make things go weird too (especially in chrome)

Comment: @JaromandaX - this is unlikely a cache issue without changes to the files. An `async` attribute could have this effect for sure. The `defer` attribute will not cause this problem either. In any event, this answer does not address the issue of "works once - doesn't work up refresh".

Comment: @RandyCasburn and JaromandaX - Take a look at my edit which shows the before refresh and after refresh.

Comment: @AshishChandra - those screenshots don't help - check the browser developer tools console

Comment: @RandyCasburn - I've seen Chrome do strange things on page refresh :p

Comment: @AshishChandra It seems that the "onAuthStateChanged" method only works when the state changes. then how about this:
`var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
if (user) {
  // User is signed in style.
} else {
  // No user is signed in style.
}`

Comment: @Centell should I add currentUser method and keep onAuthStateChanged or should I delete onAuthStateChanged?

Comment: Yeah it might be the correct solution. Take a loot at this. https://stackoverflow.com/a/44610656/10980551