# DOMContentLoaded not firing after navigation but fires on page reload when using javascript_pack_tag

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs, dom, webpack

I'm working with a Rails 6 rc1 project with React and Webpacker.

I'm currently using `javascript_pack_tag` to render React components in my Rails app. I'm trying not to use a gem like `react-rails` just to keep things simple.

Today I found a weird behavior where my React component would not render after the page is navigated to from a link. However, on a page reload, my component is rendered.

`Gemfile`:

```
gem 'rails', '~> 6.0.0.rc1'
gem 'pg', '>= 0.18', '< 2.0'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5'
gem 'webpacker', '~> 4.0'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.2', require: false
gem 'devise', '~>4.6'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'pry-byebug'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.8'
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end
```

`app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
....
```

`app/javascript/packs/application.js`:

```
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")

import "bootstrap"
import "../stylesheets/application"
```

`app/views/posts/new.html.erb`:

```
<%= content_tag :div,
  id: 'post_data',
  data: @post do %>
<% end %>
<div id="render_here"></div>
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'new_post' %>
```

`app/javascript/packs/new_post.jsx`: (though the React code in this file isn't really relevant for the question)

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import PostForm from '../components/PostForm';

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const node = document.getElementById('post_data');
  const data = JSON.parse(node.getAttribute('data'));
  const dom = document.querySelector('#render_here');

  ReactDOM.render(
    <PostForm post={data} />,
    dom);
});
```

With this setup, the component is not rendered after clicking on a link that navigates to the page. On page reload, the component is rendered.

I tried a number of things.

In `new_post.jsx`, after commenting everything out and leaving only `console.log(document.readyState)`, the console displays `complete` twice. On page load, it displays `loading`.

Then I tried to use jQuery's `document.ready` in `new_post.jsx`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if (pageInitialized) {
    return;
  }
  pageInitialized = true;

  console.log('render');
...
```

And again, `render` is displayed twice after the page is navigated to. On page reload, `render` is displayed once.

What is going on?

Comment: Update: I found the culprit to be `require("turbolinks").start()` inside `application.js`. Removing that line makes my component to load correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know this was resolved for you by a work around, but I came across this question as the first result in my search for the same issue, so for future reference for others having the same problem, I want to leave an explanation.

As described here [Rails 5: how to use $(document).ready() with turbo-links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36110789/rails-5-how-to-use-document-ready-with-turbo-links) a better way would be to listen for the turbolinks events.

```js
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", ()=> {
   alert("loaded");
}
```

or if you need jQuery

```js
$( document ).on("turbolinks:load", ()=> {
    alert("loaded");
}
```

CoffeScript variant:

```coffee
document.addEventListener "turbolinks:load",  ->
    alert "loaded"
```

Comment: Thanks, this really helps a lot. The workaround @jules mentioned also worked for me, but even better to understand what's going on, and not need to disable turbolinks.

Comment: Thank you! This really helped me as well. I am using a third-party tables builder in my RoR application, but the tables weren't being built on navigation, only on refresh. Changing `window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', event => {` to `window.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", event => {` fixed the problem. Thank you for your contribution!