# Assets only are being served on page refresh

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, turbolinks

I have an issue with my javascript files, seems they are not load properly in each redirect from my app. I need make a refresh to get load them.

Im using rails 5, and turbolinks 5.

This is how my *application.html.erb* asset tag helpers looks like

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

and this is my *application.js*

```
//= require rails-ujs
//= require jquery.min.js
//= require activestorage
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
//= require bootstrap.min.js
//= require bootstrap-datepicker.js
//= require circle-progress.min.js
//= require html5shiv.min.js
//= require jquery.appear.js
//= require jquery.appear.min.js
//= require jquery.countTo.js
//= require jquery.easing.1.3.js
//= require jquery.flexslider-min.js
//= require jquery.magnific-popup.min.js
//= require jquery.stellar.min.js
//= require jquery.waypoints.min.js
//= require owl.carousel.min.js
//= require respond.min.js
```

I get all my libraries from *vendor/assets/javascripts*

Comment: Have you had a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36110789/rails-5-how-to-use-document-ready-with-turbo-links. Typical `$(document).ready()` events do not work with Turbolinks.

Comment: yes, seems like is the solution but I cant change the code of all the libraries.
For now I removed turbolink from my app.

Answer (score 0):

Turbolinks 5 - to load the javascript properly use following events below :

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function () {
    // jquery javascript
    // your code snippet here

});


document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', function(event) {
    // vanilla javascript
    // your code snippet here
});
```